# playlist not displaying properly in IE & Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, jwplayer, playlist

Firefox displays my playlist to the right of the media player, which is exactly what I want, however IE and Chrome display the playlist beneath the player.

Here is an example (open it in Chrome or IE, then open it in Firefox)

http://www.realcardio.com/play_workout_DEV.php?ID=34,R15,28,R30,19

How can I get this playlist to the right of the player regardless of the browser?

Thanks!
DK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say Firefox is doing it wrong. You've got a fixed width on the `container_wrapper` and `width: 100%` on a floated `object` - which will be `720px` naturally. So there is no physical space for `jw_playlist_playlist` there. You need to adjust the width of the `object` element so that it didn't have `100%`.

```
<div id="container_wrapper" style="position: relative; width: 720px; height: 390px">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="js/player.swf" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#000000" id="container" name="container" tabindex="0">
    <div class="jw_playlist_playlist"></div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Encrease the `width` for the `container_wrapper` to `1040px` (720 + 320) and set the width of the `object` to 720 px and you will be good :)

Comment: I was able to expand the width of the container_wrapper to 1040px, but I am having trouble trying to modify the width of the object. I'm not sure how this is being created. Any suggestions? (thanks for helping me with this)

Comment: The `!important` will help you with this. In your css simply write `#container_wrapper object{width: 720px !important;}` - this will force the browser to apply this width, but surely it's better to find out why you have `width: 100%` as an attribute

Comment: Hey thanks! Playlist is displaying to the right in IE and Chrome!